# how to install and use a javascript based plugin on rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am making a rails app and having a ridiculously hard time trying to get the Redbox plugin to work. I'm pretty sure I installed everything correctly and am using it properly. When I use one of the helper methods, it seems to generate javascript properly. For example when I type:

```
<%= link_to_redbox 'hello', 'test' %>
```

it generates:

```
<a href="#" onclick="RedBox.showInline('test'); return false;">hello</a>
```

which seems correct if i want to show a non visible ( `display:none;` ) div called test.

I'm so confused on this one. I'm pretty sure it is not finding the js or something but don't see why this would be. The redbox.js link is generated as:

```
<script src="/javascripts/redbox.js?1239506092" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the css has to be inline!

Answer (score 2):

Check that the javascript file actually exists - it should be at public/javascripts/redbox.js (at least, that appears to be where it expects it to be).

Answer (score 0):

Try the version of GitHub. The current sourceforge version is pretty creaky.
http://github.com/craigambrose/redbox/tree/master

I'm using this one.

Stuff has started moving here. There is a few other forks that you might investigate. From some somments on the blog in April, it sounded like Craig may start it maintaining again, but oddly, the blog hasn't been update to point to GitHub.

There is another one 
Also, read the comments for patches and other stuff:

blog.craigambrose.com/articles/2006/09/22/redbox-release-2

The blog comments are an impromptu support forum. I applied a form within a form patch I found here.

There is another blog somewhere that has a large discussion in the comments.

The other thing- play around with Firebug to analysis the html and find the issue.